# JOOQ: fetch single row by primary key?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a primary key value and I want to fetch a record for updating, so at the moment I write:

```
AccountRecord account = db.selectFrom(ACCOUNT).
  where(ACCOUNT.ID.eq(identity.getAccountId())).fetchSingle();
```

JOOQ knows about the primary keys of my tables (such that it generates `onKey()` methods etc.) - so I was hoping for something like:

```
AccountRecord account = db.fetchByKey(ACCOUNT, identity.getAccountId())
```

But that doesn't seem to be a thing.
Is there a more concise way of using the JOOQ API to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DSLContext.fetchSingle(Table, Condition)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchSingle-org.jooq.Table-org.jooq.Condition-):

```java
AccountRecord account = db.fetchSingle(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT.ID.eq(identity.getAccountId()));
```

The generated `ACCOUNT` reference does not have a type reference to the key type, so the syntax you suggested is not possible. You could of course [extend the code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code/) to produce a method that takes the primary key value and produces a `Condition`:

```java
class Account {
    ..
    public Condition byKey(Long accountId) {
        return ID.eq(accountId);
    }
    public AccountRecord fetchByKey(DSLContext ctx, Long accountId) {
        return ctx.fetchSingle(this, byKey(accountId));
    }
}
```

And now use the above:

```java
AccountRecord account = ACCOUNT.fetchByKey(db, identity.getAccountId());
```